# how to prove the following relation

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f$ be a continuous function on [0,1] differentiable on (0,1) such that $f(1)=0$ then prove that for some $c$ $$cf'(c)+ f(c)=0$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
Consider the function $g(x)=xf(x)$, and apply Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Wow ,i feel like a fool now :p,

Comment: @user142634 You shouldn't. One has to come up with the function which I think is hard without prior experience.

Comment: @user1337 How do you know that if f(x) is cont in [0, 1] and diff in (0,1), then g(x) is cont in [0, 1] and diff in (0,1)?

Comment: @BCLC $g(x)$ is the product of two functions which are continuous in $[0,1]$, and is thus continuous there. Similarly $g(x)$ is the product of two functions which are differentiable in $(0,1)$, and is thus differentiable there.

Comment: @user142634 You shouldn't. The key here is to recognize the expression in your question as the product rule applied to $xf(x)$ at the point $x=c$. This might require some experience.

Comment: @user1337 Oh I remember now. This was proved in Advanced Calculus...are beginning Calculus students then expected to take it on faith?

Comment: @BCLC They don't have to, if they are independent enough.